Visual puzzle involving mathematical operations
Try this puzzle. It involves mathematical operations. Created on my own.

Transcription (for those who aren't able to see images):
Key:
+--+----------+
|o |orange    |
|g |green     |
|lb|light blue|
|b |blue      |
|r |red       |
+--+----------+

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|o 4|b 7|g 5|r 3|g 2|b 5|r 3|r 5|lb1|o 7|208
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|o 8|r 8|r 2|o 4|b 9|g 4|lb8|r 9|b 3|r 9|308
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|o 9|o 4|g 6|b 6|o 7|lb6|g 4|lb5|r 2|o 9|367
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|lb4|b 4|g 2|r 9|r 3|o 7|b 3|g 8|b 2|g 3| ?
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|r 1|o 8|lb8|r 3|b 2|r 5|g 4|b 6|g 7|lb2|239
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|o 9|b 8|r 9|g 3|lb2|o 4|b 9|g 3|lb3|r 7|293
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|o 4|g 5|r 5|lb4|lb7|b 2|g 6|o 7|o 4|r 6|282
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|r 1|b 8|lb4|o 1|g 1|r 9|o 2|r 8|lb4|lb7|180
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|o 3|r 2|r 8|lb1|g 8|lb4|lb2|g 0|o 9|b 6|243
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
 316 279 223 157 216 230 204 266 205 288


I’m not sure if there exists some kind of coincidence, but I noticed…
step 1. add up the numbers with the same color of each row/ column
$$
\begin{array}{cc|ccccc}
row/col & value & orange & blue & yellow & red & light blue \\ 
row\ 1 & 208 & 11 & 12 & 7   & 11  & 1 \\
row\ 2 & 308 & 12 & 12 & 4   & 28  & 8  \\
row\ 3 & 367 & 29 & 6  & 10  & 2   & 11  \\
row\ 4 & ?   & 7  & 9  & 13  & 12  & 4  \\ 
row\ 5 & 239 & 8  & 8  & 11  & 9   & 10  \\
row\ 6 & 293 & 13 & 17 & 6   & 16  & 5  \\
row\ 7 & 282 & 15 & 2  & 11  & 11  & 11  \\
row\ 8 & 180 & 3  & 8  & 1   & 18  & 15  \\
row\ 9 & 243 & 12 & 6  & 8   & 10  & 7  \\
col\ 1 & 316 & 37 & 0  & 0   & 2   & 4  \\
col\ 2 & 279 & 12 & 27 & 5   & 10  & 0  \\
col\ 3 & 223 & 0  & 0  & 13  & 24  & 12  \\
col\ 4 & 157 & 5  & 6  & 3   & 15  & 5  \\
col\ 5 & 216 & 7  & 11 & 11  & 3   & 9  \\
col\ 6 & 230 & 11 & 7  & 4   & 14  & 10  \\
col\ 7 & 204 & 2  & 12 & 14  & 3   & 10  \\
col\ 8 & 266 & 7  & 6  & 11  & 22  & 5  \\
col\ 9 & 205 & 13 & 5  & 7   & 2   & 8  \\ 
col\ 10 & 288 & 16 & 6 & 3   & 22  & 9  \\
\end{array}
$$
step 2. applying:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
11 & 12 & 7 & 11 & 1 \\
12 & 12 & 4 & 28 & 8 \\
29 & 6 & 10 & 2 & 11 \\
8 & 8 & 11 & 9 & 10 \\
13 & 17 & 6 & 16 & 5 \\
15 & 2 & 11 & 11 & 11\\
3 & 8 & 1 & 18 & 15 \\
12 & 6 & 8 & 10& 7\\
37 & 0 & 0& 2 &4\\
12 & 27 & 5 & 10 & 0 \\
0 & 0& 13 & 24 & 12 \\
5 & 6& 3 & 15 & 5 \\
7 & 11 & 11 & 3 & 9 \\
11 & 7 & 4 & 14 & 10 \\
2 & 12 & 14 & 3 &10\\
7& 6 & 11&22&5\\
13&5&7&2&8\\
16&6&3&22&9\\
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
8 \\ 4 \\ 7 \\ 4 \\ 3 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{232} \\ 308 \\ 367 \\ 239 \\ 293 \\ 282 \\ 180 \\ \color{red}{237} \\ 316 \\ 279 \\ 223 \\ \color{red}{160} \\ 216 \\ 230 \\ 204 \\ \color{red}{260} \\ 205 \\ 288
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This calculation process seems work well except for the numbers with red color (232, 237, 160, 260)…
